# how to use callUDF?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.3.0 and try to use callUDF. But I got an error that the second the parameter's type is wrong. It requires `scala.collection.Seq<org.apache.spark.sql.column>`, but `col()` function returns `org.apache.spark.sql.column`.

I have see many people use `callUDF("udfName",col("colName"))` like this safely, but why I can't?

```
public static UDF1<String,Option<Integer>>normSex = new UDF1<String, Option<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Option<Integer> call(String d) throws Exception {
        if (null == d)
            return Option.apply(null);
        else{
            if(d.equals("male"))
                return Some.apply(0);
            else
                return Some.apply(1);
        }
    }
};
```

And then I register it

```
spark.udf().register("normSex",normSex, DataTypes.StringType);
```

when I try to use it like this

```
Dataset<Row> projection=df.select(callUDF("normSex",col("Sex)));
```

this is where I get the error:

> Error: java: incompatible types: org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be converted to scala.collection.Seq